# Что происходит, когда заходишь за границы массива

Tags: c#, delphi, массивы

Что происходит, когда заходишь за границы массива ? Когда i++ и попадает за границу массива, что будет ? `(until (PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, i] <> (-1));)`
Переписываю на C# там за границы массива нельзя заходить.

**Delphi**

```
for KCO:=0 to 3 do
  for Tip:=1 to 6 do
  begin
    CCO:=1;
    repeat
      if PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO] = (-1) then
        PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:= 0
      else
      begin
        i:=CCO;
        repeat 
          Inc(i);
        until (PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, i] <> (-1));
        PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:= PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, i] -  PKTS[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO];

        case Tip of
          2,5  : PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:= PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]*5;

          3,4,6: PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]:= PDL[1, 1]^[KCO, Tip, CCO]*8;
        end;
      end;
      Inc(CCO);
    until CCO=16;
  end;
```

**C#**

```
for (int kco = 0; kco < 4; kco++)
{
    for (int tip = 0; tip < 6; tip++)
    {
        for (int cco = 0; cco < 16; cco++)
        {
            if (pkts[kco, tip, cco] == -1)
            {
                pdl[kco, tip, cco] = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                int i = cco;
                do
                {
                    i++;
                } while (pkts[kco, tip, i] == -1);

                short left = pkts[kco, tip, i];
                short right = pkts[kco, tip, cco];
                pdl[kco, tip, cco] = (short)(left - right);
                switch (tip)
                {
                    case 2:
                    case 5:
                        pdl[kco, tip, cco] = (short)(pdl[kco, tip, cco] * 5);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                    case 4:
                    case 6:
                        pdl[kco, tip, cco] = (short)(pdl[kco, tip, cco] * 8);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Код ваш выглядит очень не читаемым. Что он делает, трудно понять сходу. Я считаю это плохо. В C# много средств для того, чтобы не писать процедуры так. Конечно, иногда важнее производительность, и такой подход к написанию _может_ оказаться правильным. Но и тогда ничего не мешает давать переменным понятные названия.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Delphi зависит от настроек компилятора.

Если включены проверки на выходы за диапазоны, то поднимается исключение.
Если нет - получаете мусор, но работа не прерывается.